# c# Regex matches too generous

Tags: c#, regex

I need to confirm the format of a customer number, which needs to be the format of `#####-##` (# being a 0-9 digit and the dash being a literal dash).

I built the regex using RegexBuddy (which lets you type in test strings to ensure it is right).  I ended up with:

```
\d{5}-\d{2}
```

This tests well, giving me the desired outcomes - a 'hit' on:

```
12345-01
```

and no match for

```
12345
```

This tool provides the code to use this regex in various languages - I want to use this in C# to return true for a match against the entire string.  This gives me the below, which I have put into code.

```
Regex.IsMatch(c.Bill_To, @"\A\d{5}-\d{2}\Z")
```

This code however returns my `12345` as a match!

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I just ran `Regex.IsMatch("12345", @"\A\d{5}-\d{2}\Z")`, and it claims `false`...

Comment: Unless you want to allow `"૧૨૩૪૫-૦૧"` (12345-01 in Gujarati) as a valid customer number, use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, or specify `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` as the second argument to `Regex.IsMatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegEx works correctly. Try checking the c.Bill_To value.

```
        bool testResult;

        var testSuccess = "12345-01";
        testResult = Regex.IsMatch(testSuccess, @"\A\d{5}-\d{2}\Z"); //is True

        var testFail = "12345";
        testResult = Regex.IsMatch(testFail, @"\A\d{5}-\d{2}\Z"); //is False
```

Comment: Thanks mate, as it turns out you are right and it was another bug :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue your are having.  If one of your customer numbers is in a string along with additional content, then the pattern you have isn't working. Specifying both `\A` and `\Z` means your customer number must start at the beginning of the string and end at the end of the string in order to be matched. `\A` is like `^` which matches the beginning of a string, and `\Z` is like `$` which matches the end of a string -- except that they ignore whether the `MultiLine` option was specified.

Try using this pattern: `\b\d{5}-\d{2}\b`

It will only match your customer numbers if they are on a boundary between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters.  That also means you can find customer numbers even if they aren't separated by just whitespace as shown in the last test case in the following [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) script.

```
const string pattern = @"\b\d{5}-\d{2}\b";

Regex.IsMatch("12345", pattern).Dump(); // no match
Regex.IsMatch("12345-12", pattern).Dump(); // match
Regex.IsMatch("12345-1234", pattern).Dump(); // no match
Regex.IsMatch("word 12345 word", pattern).Dump(); // no match
Regex.IsMatch("word 12345-12 word", pattern).Dump(); // match
Regex.IsMatch("word 12345-1234 word", pattern).Dump(); // no match
Regex.IsMatch("word@12345-12@word", pattern).Dump(); // match
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll try these permutations.  Didn't realise the pre and post aspects of the filter.